# conda build how to use subpackages

Tags: python, build, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to build my python package with conda and I'm having some trouble.

The package is basically two subpackages and at the moment, it works fine if installed with python using setuptools. I can easily call the subpackages with:

`python -m my_package.the_subpackage`

My real question is first of all, what do I have to do to differently with conda build for this to translate to my conda package.

And secondly, how do I call my subpackages assuming it get installed with conda? Is it the same, or is it `my_package the_subpackage` or something similar?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Once things are installed the behavior should be identical. Any differences would be due to differences in the conda recipe. I'd expect all you need to do is ensure `setup.py` call to `setup()` contains both packages in `packages=[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, your first question is how to create conda packages for python if you already have setup.py. The answer is pretty common, just google it.
One helpful reference: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html

Very short (and not necessarily generic way) is:

```
conda install conda-build
mkdir conda-recipe && pushd conda-recipe
echo "python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed" > build.sh
touch meta.yaml # populate meta.yaml with proper config. Something to start with: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/_downloads/d42b166defebcb482accb83c6edec8c9/meta.yaml

# with <CWD> being your current working directory.
popd && conda-build <CWD>/conda-recipe -croot build --output-folder <CWD>/dist/conda
```

For the second question, consulting https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#implicit-metapackages , one way is to define different subpackages via the `outputs` configuration.

Rough config for your case:

```
package:
  name: my_package

requirements:
  host: 
   - python
  run:
    - my_package-the_subpackage1
    - my_package-the_subpackage2

outputs:
  - name: my_package.the_subpackage1
    requirements:
      - some-dep
    script: some_build_script.sh
  - name: my_package.the_subpackage2
    requirements:
      - some-other-dep
    script: some_other_build_script.sh
```

this will create 3 pacakges (2 subpackages and a parent meta package having dependency on the subpackages.
to install them, you can do:

`conda install my_package` to get the whole thing
or

`conda install my_package.the_subpackage1` to only install the first subpackage.